# zooming mandelbrot set second time doesnot let it zoom in desired place

Tags: c++, c, opengl, mandelbrot

I am using opengl/c++ to draw mandelbrot set and trying to zoom into. I am able to zoom for the first time and zooms where i want (by clicking), but when i try to zoom next time it does not zoom where i intended to zoom instead it shift and zoom little bit far from the place i want to zoom. 
I use

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double dividecubesby  = 700;
double left = -2.0;
double right = 2.0;
double bottom = -2.0;
double top = 2.0;
int maxiteration = 128;
int zoomlevel = 3;
double baseSize = 4.0;
double Size = 0.0;
double xco=0.0;
double yco=0.0;

    void   SetXYpos(int px,int py)
    {
        xco = left+(right-left)*px/dividecubesby;
        yco = top-(top-bottom)*py/dividecubesby;
    }

   void keyPressed(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
   {

       int xx= x;
       int yy= y;
       setXYpos(xx,yy);


       Size = 0.5*(pow(2.0, (-zoomlevel)));



       switch(key){

       case 'z':

      left   =  xco -  Size;
      right  =  xco +  Size;
      bottom =  yco -  Size;
      top    =  yco +  Size;

      dividecubesby = dividecubesby+100;        
      maxiteration  = maxiteration+100; 
  zoomlevel=zoomlevel+1;

      glutPostRedisplay();
      break;
      }

  }

    int mandtest(double Cr, double Ci)
 {


    double Zr = 0.0;
    double Zi = 0.0;
    int times = 0;
    double temp;
    Zr = Zr+Cr;
    Zi = Zi+Ci;

    while ((((Zr*Zr)+(Zi*Zi))<=4) && (times < maxiteration)){

       temp = (Zr*Zr)-(Zi*Zi);
       Zi = 2*Zr*Zi;

       Zr = temp+Cr;
       Zi = Zi+Ci;                 

       times = times+1;  


    }

  return times;

}


        void display(void)
 {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    double deltax = ((right - left)/(dividecubesby-1));
    double deltay = ((top- bottom)/(dividecubesby-1));

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluOrtho2D(left,right,bottom,top);


    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

    for(double x= left;x<=right;x += deltax ){
        for(double y= bottom; y<=top;y +=  deltay ){
        if((mandtest(x,y))==maxiteration){
            glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f); 
            glVertex2f(x,y);

        }
        else {
        glColor3f((float)mandtest(x,y)/10,0.0f,(float)mandtest(x,y)/30);
                    glVertex2f(x,y);
            }

        }
     }
    glEnd();

glFlush();
}
```

to calculate where the mouse is clicked interms of the cartesian co-ordinate [-2,2]

px and py are pixel coordinate

Comment: please post some code, or -if you are using a known program- the piece of code you are believing it's part of the problem

Comment: @linello thank you for the response  ... i have edited some code into my previous code .. sorry for it being messy

Comment: mmh...why are you using keyboardPress callback to get the mouse position? It would be better if you'd implement a mouse callback rather than using the keyboard press to get (x,y) coordinate of the mouse.

The problem comes from the misunderstood use of the keyPressed function instead of mouseFunc, so try to remove the setXYpos in keyboard press and implement a mouseFunc, this will let you apply the transformation in the **actual** coordinate of the mouse

http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node50.html

Comment: I tried with the mouse too but the problem persists (no change at all) ... the co ordinate it gives is same for the both case ( in pixel form) .. i dont know man ... for first case it works perfectly its the second,third etc cases it just shift away and away from the place i clicked .. i am thinking SizeReal and SizeImage might cause problem but still cant say for sure .. and yes using mouseFunc is way more easier than using keyboard press ... otherwise i had to place mouse in place where i want to zoom and then press 'z' .. now just a click will do thank you for that the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 2):

You have too many variables. What defines the width of your image? `(right - left)`? `baseSize + f(zoomLevel)`? `SizeReal`? It's not clear whose job it is to set whom and who is used by whom, so you cannot hope to update everything consistently.

Also, why does `dividecubesby` increase by a flat 500 while the image size halves with every zoom? Where is the width/height of your window system window which define the limits of the clicked coordinates?

My suggestion is to start from scratch and maybe draw a graph of who updates whom (`left/right -> imageWidth`). Make sure that you get the correct clicked coordinates independent of what your drawing window (left/right/top/bottom) is, and go on from there. As it is, I think your first zoom works correctly by accident.

Comment: Thank you aib for the compliment i kind of understood what you said and changed a little bit ... i have edit the above question ... please can you comment on that too .. after changing it works more or less better .. let me know if i have done it correctly or not ... at least for now it works ... but i am afraid whether its a good solution or not :(

Comment: @gunda: it looks like you have not addressed most of my concerns. You should start from scratch. It's usually much easier than dealing with messy code like this.